# Ionic app in Android studio with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework

Test ionic app in android studio with backend spring boot

how to test my ionic application on an android studio emulator locally My app needs back spring boot for apis. My problem is what url should I put? I've seen answers saying to put the ipv4 address but it doesn't work for me